# SpringBoot - UTF8 & Controller

Tags: spring-mvc, utf-8, spring-boot

I am using SpringBoot and Spring MVC for my Web Application and when I submit any form my controller gets the information encoded with ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8.

My application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/pfg
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.sqlScriptEncoding=UTF-8
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes=true
spring.messages.encoding=UTF-8
server.tomcat.uri-encoding=UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML5
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
```

I also have this ServerInitializer class:

```
@Configuration
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(PfgApplication.class);
    }


    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter() {
      CharacterEncodingFilter filter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
      filter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
      filter.setForceEncoding(true);
      return filter;
    }



}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: That looks very suspicious to me. What versions are you using?  Spring Boot 1.2 has an explicit story about it and it's all UTF-8 by default if you're using the embedded container which apparently you should. That filter is created for you by the way. What makes you think it's ISO-8859-1 encoded exactly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using 1.3.0.M5 by chance? In that case there's a bug and you might want to consider using the workaround:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3912

```
@Autowired
private HttpEncodingProperties httpEncodingProperties;
@Bean
public OrderedCharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter() {
  OrderedCharacterEncodingFilter filter = new OrderedCharacterEncodingFilter();
  filter.setEncoding(this.httpEncodingProperties.getCharset().name());
  filter.setForceEncoding(this.httpEncodingProperties.isForce());
  filter.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
  return filter;
}
```

Comment: Only just now saw that @user3692964's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32697248/53444 is to pretty old question by now. Leaving the answer up as it's relevant now; Will take it down when 1.3.0 is released.

Answer (score 1):

for Example

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user", **produces="text/html;charset=UTF-8"**)

public class UserController{
}
```

add blackbody part is ok!

Comment: Remove the ** like:

@RequestMapping(value="/user", produces="text/html;charset=UTF-8")
public class UserController{
}